How to make a slide presents in the following order slides?
I would like to make the frame presents step by step in the following order:
%% This frame begin

Step 1


Step 2


Step 3


Step 4


Step 5



%% This frame end
And the MWE is the following:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.6\linewidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item ITEM1
        \item ITEM2
        \item ITEM3
        \item ITEM4
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[height=1em,width=3em]{example-image-a}\\
      \includegraphics[height=1em,width=3em]{example-image-a}\\
      \includegraphics[height=1em,width=3em]{example-image-a}\\
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=5em]{example-image}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


You could add the images to your items and then uncover them step by step:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item ITEM1\hfill\includegraphics[height=1em,width=3em]{example-image-a}%
    \item ITEM2\hfill\includegraphics[height=1em,width=3em]{example-image-a}%
    \item ITEM3\hfill\includegraphics[height=1em,width=3em]{example-image-a}%
    \item ITEM4
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{5.5em}
    \centering
    \includegraphics<5>[height=5em]{example-image}%
  \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


If you'd like to keep your columns:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.6\linewidth}
      \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item ITEM1
        \item ITEM2
        \item ITEM3
        \item ITEM4
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
      \uncover<1->{\includegraphics[height=1em,width=3em]{example-image-a}}
      
      \uncover<2->{\includegraphics[height=1em,width=3em]{example-image-a}}
      
      \uncover<3->{\includegraphics[height=1em,width=3em]{example-image-a}}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  
  \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{5.5em}
    \centering
    \includegraphics<5>[height=5em]{example-image}%
  \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Hmmm…There’s a problem that the three images on the rignt column is center aligned vertically to the four items on the left column…

@Meiu I added a second approach with columns

Perfect! Thank you very much!

@Meiu You're welcome!
